# Relativistic two-body problem with Lorentz interaction

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

### Setup and relevant equations

Suppose that two oppositely charged particles interact with each other through the Lorentz force that one particle feels due to the motion of the other. Let $\mathbf{r}$ be the relative position vector and let's assume the following:

1. $r\equiv\|\mathbf{r}\|$ is constant
2. the velocity of each particle has constant magnitude
3. the velocity of each particle is vertical to the relative position vector
4. the velocities have opposite directions

which are the conditions for circular orbits around the center of mass, with constant angular velocity, let's say $\omega$. From the relativistic equation of motion of the relative position vector in polar coordinates and the above assumptions, I derived the following condition:
$$\tilde{\mu }{{\omega }^{2}}r=K\frac{1}{{{r}^{2}}}\left( 1+\tfrac{1}{{{c}^{2}}}{{v}_{1}}{{v}_{2}} \right)$$
where:
$$\frac{1}{{\tilde{\mu }}}=\frac{1}{{{m}_{2}}{{\gamma }_{2}}}+\frac{1}{{{m}_{1}}{{\gamma }_{1}}}\quad,\quad{K}=\tfrac{\left|q_1q_2\right|}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$$
whereas $m_i$, $v_i$ and $\gamma_i$ are, respectively, the *mass*, the *magnitude of the velocity* and the corresponding *Lorentz gamma factor* of particle $i$. Furthermore, in the center of mass frame, the velocities were given by:
$${{v}_{i}}=\frac{{\tilde{\mu }}}{{{m}_{i}}{{\gamma }_{i}}}\omega r$$

### The goal an attempt for achieving it

I want to solve for $\omega$ as a function of $K$, $r$, $m_1$ and $m_2$. I have tried to use the circular orbit condition, so as to substitute $\omega$ in the expressions for the velocities, and I got a pretty nasty system of equations for the $\gamma_i$'s. If this is solved, then I could replace the solutions in the circular orbit condition and then solve for $\omega$.

### The question

Since the thus-described equation looks unsolvable to me (and to Mathematica as well), does anybody have an idea on how to solve for $\omega$ for a given radius $r$? In the non-relativistic case, where we don't have these bloody velocity-dependent terms, this is trivial. Is it really that complicated in the relativistic case, or do I miss something?

Comment: Not an answer, but trying to solve the perturbatively relativistic case can help give insight into the full solution.

Comment: Purely intuitively, I expect that $\gamma_i$ will be proportional to coth of a fraction that has (an increasing function of) $m_i$ and $K$ in the numerator and $r$ and the total mass in the denominator. I got even nastier equations from this ansatz. Would you agree with it?

Comment: I was able to reduce it to a quartic equation so mathematica could give me an expression. Of course it is a complicated expression though. Is this useful? What is your nasty system for the $\gamma$s? I didn't get something nasty, but I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: I got a sixth order equation, but now I try a different approach by defining new variables. It looks promising...

Comment: ...was your solution given explicitly by mathematica or by roots of higher order equations, as it happened in my case?